# Vue JS Axios Post Request Sending Null to PHP

Tags: php, json, vue.js

So I have an image uploaded in Vue JS and I send the POST request to a Laravel Route. The image gets uploaded, saved on my local and sent to an API. The API request returns its JSON response on client side (as expected) BUT I cannot do anything with this response on PHP, it returns null in PHP. I can only see the JSON response client side, which is weird. I have been trying to figure this out for a couple of days.

Here is my Vue JS code that uploads a picture:

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
    export default{
        data(){
            return {
                image: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onFileChange(e) {
                let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
                if (!files.length)
                    return;
                this.createImage(files[0]);
            },
            createImage(file) {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                let vm = this;
                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    vm.image = e.target.result;
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            },
            upload(){
                    let formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('image', this.image);
                    console.log(this.image) ;
                    axios.post( 'nova-vendor/ad-asset-upload/add',
                     formData,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token.content
                                }
                    }
                    ).then(function (response){
                            console.log(response);
                        })
                        .catch(function(){
                        console.log('FAILURE!!');
                    });
                },
            }
        }
```

Vue JS returns a base64 image and I convert it in the PHP controller to jpg or png and it uploads to the API / locally. I see the response on client side like this:

```
{"error":false,"size":27410,"filename":"yJCH2T","ext":"png","url":"https://vgy.me/u/yJCH2T","image":"https://vgy.me/yJCH2T.png","delete":"https://vgy.me/delete/eGGhib4gPY2a"}
```

In PHP no matter what I do I cannot get the JSON data, BUT I CAN get the JSON when I replicate my steps on vanilla php without Larval or Vue.

Here is my PHP code once the base64 string is converted into an image.

```
 $ch = curl_init('https://vgy.me/upload');
    $file = new CURLFile($file, $type, $filename );
    $data = array('file' => $file, 'title' => 'Beautiful Flowers', 'description' => 'A beautiful photo of flowers at the local park.');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $ok =  curl_exec($ch);
    $json = json_decode($ok, true);
```

**So I would expect**`$json['image']` to return the image url from JSON string, but its null.

In case you were wondering about my image conversion logic here it is...

```
        $data = $request->input('image');
        $pos  = strpos($data, ';');
        $type = explode(':', substr($data, 0, $pos))[1];
        $folderPath = "storage/";
        $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $request->input('image'));
        $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
        $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
        $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
        if ( $type == "image/jpeg" || $type == "image/jpg"){

            $file = $folderPath . uniqid() . '.jpg';
            $filename = uniqid() . '.jpg';
        } else if ( $type == "image/png" ) 
        {

            $file = $folderPath . uniqid() . '.png';
            $filename = uniqid() . '.png';
        }
        $img = file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

to my CURL code. But now I guess I have to go back and rework my original Guzzle Package I created that works in just regular old PHP / HTML.